# Is LXLE more resource-intensive than Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu

I'm using Lubuntu on an Acer Aspire One. It works well, and I'm happy with it. Recently, however, I came across the Lubuntu-derived LXLE distribution and it looks interesting. But I'm wondering whether all the added eye candy, etc. makes the distribution use more memory and/or slows down (other) applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at [the homepage](http://lxle.net/), I can't see how it would be significantly different from Lubuntu resource wise especially since it is also LXDE based and bills itself as "light on resources" and "primarily for aging computers".

Better eye candy, in the context of the *same* [desktop environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment) (DE)-- in this case LXDE -- probably does not significantly increase resource usage; it comes from design.  With regard to "slowness", the DE doesn't do all that much if you are doing other things, but if using openGL based "desktop effects" (spinning cubes and all that), these will be noticeably slower on slower systems without hardware support (i.e., nvidia or ATI cards).  In any case, [this guy](http://jeffhoogland.blogspot.ca/2013/02/comparison-of-linux-desktops-opengl.html) claims that openGL runs faster inside LXDE than other DE's.